# How to create step definition for feature file (using language: python, package: behave, extension: cucumber, Editor: vs code)?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, cucumber, python-behave

[(configuration => language: python, package: behave, extension: cucumber, Editor: vs code OS: Ubuntu 20.04)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75Be3.png)
I'm unable to create step definitions for feature files in vs code.
I have tried "go to step definition" and "peek" options, but it didn't work for me (screenshot1).
I have written manually snippet for "given" clause (screenshot2).

```
@given("Get_the_result_using_GET_endpoint")
    def step_imp():
        url = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2"
        response = requests.get(url)
        print(response)
        # print(response.content)
        json_response = json.loads(response.text)
        # print(json_response)

        pages = json_response.get('total_pages')
        print(pages)
        assert pages == 2
```

Please refer to the attached screenshots.

Comment: I think you are missing the right folder structure and `steps` directory: https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gherkin.html. Another thing is that you are missing `context` variable in you step function and it actually should look like: `def step_impl(context)` not `step_imp()`

Comment: It worked for me. The link was very helpful. Thank you!